# How can I split up a date into three select boxes with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have my date as a UNIX timestamp,

```
dateOfBirth = 1384369855;
$scope.dob = dateOfBirth;
```

In my view, how can I pass that to a model to have three fields, one for `day`, `month` and `year`?

Comment: Can you post an example what `$scope.dob` equals?

Comment: Changed it to include the timestamp

Comment: Should be January 5th, 1970, yes?

Comment: @tymeJV i think it in sec, x 1000

Comment: Not used to working with UNIX timestamps, just taking my best guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    days:   <select ng-model="selectedday" ng-options="selectedday for selectedday in days"></select>
    month:  <select ng-model="selectedmonth" ng-options="selectedmonth for selectedmonth in months"></select>
    years:  <select ng-model="selectedyear" ng-options="selectedyear for selectedyear in years"></select>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $scope.days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
    $scope.months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    $scope.years = [2010,2011,2012,2013,2014];

     $scope.theDate = new Date(1384369855000);

    $scope.selectedyear = $scope.theDate.getFullYear();
    $scope.selectedmonth = $scope.months[$scope.theDate.getMonth()];
    $scope.selectedday = $scope.theDate.getDate();
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/51/)**</kbd>

Comment: How do I incorporate this in my view?

Comment: I advise you to use a datepicker plugin, like [AngularStrap - Datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker), check [the demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QAxwgLSWQaYbGzkzeu4g?p=preview)

Comment: @dawuut well, for that basic logic datepicker? I think too expensive

Comment: Our requirement requires three select boxes

Comment: @Shamoon what do you want to put into selected boxes? you have only one value per selected box, or i miss something

Comment: I need to fill it with 1-31 for the day, Jan - Dec for the month and so on

Comment: Correction: `getDay()` should be `getDate()`. The former returns the ordinal day of the *week* (because the Javascript date class interface is a bit nonsensical)